# How to make the keyboard go away

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have seen other threads answering this question but my issue is I don't understand what is being said, being new to programming. My app has a User ID and Password text field to let the user log in with current credentials. When they data is entered, I want the user to be able to make the keyboard go away.

Here is what I have done. The problem is, nothing happens. Or, I don't understand what I have written and am not testing it correctly (although I am testing it as I would expect my novice users to, and it is not acting as expected).  I appreciate any help you can give.

These text fields and this button are defined in the class ViewController: UIViewController. Then the function to hide the keyboard is in the `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
@IBOutlet var loginEntered: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var passwordEntered: UITextField!

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.logInError = 1

        func textFieldShouldReturn(passwordEntered: UITextField!) -> Bool {

            passwordEntered.resignFirstResponder()

            return true

        }
```

Thank you again,

Greg

Comment: Did you assign the `UITextFieldDelegate` to your view controller and set your text fields to that delegate?

Comment: Does the method get called at all when you set a breakpoint on it? You need to be sure you are conforming to the UITextFieldDelegate and that you set all your textFields' delegates to self. If you don't do that this code will never run.

Comment: First thing, you need to attach UiTextFieldDelegate to both textfields. Also, not necessary in this case but it would be a good practice to do resignFirstResponder for your other textfield.

Comment: Have you really defined `textFieldShouldReturn` _inside_ `viewDidLoad`, as you question's code seems to show? In that case, that's your problem right there.

Comment: Thanks to all you who responded. My problem is you have asked me questions that I do not understand. @Aaron, what is UITextFieldDelegate and how/why would I add it to my view controller? Then how do I set the text fields to that delegate?

Comment: @Dare, I don't even know how to respond to what you are saying. Can you explain to me what a breakpoint is? What does the rest of your comment refer to?

Comment: @natasha, your comment sounds the same as Aaron's, is it or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @matt, I did define textFieldShouldReturn inside vewDidLoad. If that is not the correct place, where is?

Comment: The "textFieldShouldReturn" is a method. You can not implement a method inside another method, you can only call a method inside another. Besides, you don't need to call the textFieldShouldReturn method at all. It will automatically be called when the keyboard's return key is pressed, IF you have connected the delegate properly. So, make sure, your textField's delegate is connected properly. I gave the complete solution. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the step by step approach of your problem. I will show you mostly with storyboard.

Step 1: Go to the Project Navigator on left and select Main.stoyboard and select the ViewController in which you want to add your textfields and button.

[image]

and then add the 2 UITextfields and one UIButton by dragging and dropping from the object library in your ViewController in storyboard.

[image]

Step 2: Add your IBOutlets for the textfields and button in your ViewController-

[image]

Spet 3: Go back to your storyboard, select the view controller and click on the right most icon which is called the connection inspector. There you will see the your textfields and button names under the Outlet.

[image]

Now connect them by clicking and holding the outlet from the inspector and drag from there to the desired textfield or button. Do that for all. If you miss any connection then your code has no way to determine which variable corresponds to which component(TextFields or Button).

[image]

Step 4: Select your TextField, userID from the storyboard, then in the Connection inspector, you will see an Outlet called "delegate"(see the image below). It is this specific textfield's(userID) delegate which you need to assign to your ViewController. This tells your Textfield that, the View Controller will implement its delegate methods.

[image]

Do the same for the "password" TextField too. After you connect the password textField's delegate to the view controller, it will look something like this -

[image]

Now you are good to go.

Step 5:
Finally, go to your View Controller and add the "func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool" delegate method.

[image]

This is the complete solution which I tested in my device too. Hope I have made it clear..

Comment: Thank you for you very complete answer to my issue. I have followed your instructions and I am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

simply there are two steps you need to do

1. The class should conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol by declaring  beside the inherited superclass of what you use `, UITextFieldDelegate` so for example if your class inherits from UIViewController it will be like that 
       `class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate`
2. since the class now conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol put this delegate method somewhere in the class `optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool`
   and return `YES`

Hey check the apple developer guide for it here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:

Comment: Thank you for that information. I have read the guide you linked and it helped some. I added the , UITextFieldDelegate as you outlined and the method was defined in the class.  Still not working.  Here is what I have. optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ passwordEntered: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        //passwordEntered.resignFirstResponder()
        
        return true
        
    }          I get a yellow triangle to the left and when I click on it is says, "Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'passwordEntered' has no keyword argument name.

Comment: i might missed saying that you should set the textfields as delegates by add using  `self.textfield.delegate=self;`

Comment: @M_Wally I added that syntax inside the optional func but it did not change my error.  Sorry to be so obtuse but what am I missing?              optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ passwordEntered: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        self.passwordEntered.delegate=self;
        
        passwordEntered.resignFirstResponder()
        
        return true
        
    }

Comment: add it in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I moved that to the viewDidLoad method but I still have the same error.  "Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'passwordEntered' has no keyword argument name."